# Hemeatology vs Hematology

Tags: terminology, hematology

Is there a difference between "Hemeatology" and "Hematology" as physician medical specialties?  Or are these spelling variants, like "Haematology" vs "Hematology"?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). I myself have never encountered that variant before, and when I search for it most sites offering this variant are not official websites or something peer reviewed. Could you share a source where you encountered *hemeatology*? Thanks!

Comment: The difference is one is a specialty and the other is a misspelling.

Comment: Source is notes self-typed by physicians indicating specialty to whom they would refer certain patients.  (Don't worry, I'm not in charge of patient care, the context is research)

Answer (score 1):

It's just a misspelling of *haematology*, which is the British spelling of *hematology*. *Hematology* and *haematology* are synonyms, and there is no such word *hemeatology*.

From the [Merriam-Webster Medical Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hematology#medicalDictionary) (emphasis mine):

> hematology
>
> noun he·ma·tol·o·gy
>
> Medical Definition of hematology
>
> plural hematologies
>
> ```
> :  a medical science that deals with the blood and blood-forming organs
> ```
>
> **hematologist or chiefly British haematologist** -jəst\
>
> noun
>
> **Variants of hematology**
>
> **or chiefly British haematology**
>   \ˌhē-mə-ˈtäl-ə-jē\